# iOS 5: Changing foreground color using attributed string in UITextView

Tags: ios5, uitextview, core-text, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

This code works well on iOS 6

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:[textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange]];

[textView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

However NSForegroundColorAttributeName is undefined in iOS 5, so I want the equivalent of the previous code that works in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent is to use the kCTForegroundColorAttributeName with a CGColorRef for the color.

See my CoreText introduction here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/